# How can I compare the rows of two CSV files based on the similarities in them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

file1.csv looks like:

[image]

file2.csv looks like:

[image]

The desired output is "updated file2.csv":

[image]

file1.csv is to be taken as reference and shouldn't be altered.
The rows in file2.csv should be rearranged such that every row in file1.csv be corresponding to every row in file2.csv (based on the similarity of values), as shown in the images shared.
If there are **extra** rows in file2.csv that are not similar to any rows in file1.csv, they can be eliminated (keeping in mind that number of rows in file1.csv should be equal to the updated csv file.).

Comment: I have installed all these versions of python on my system.

Comment: can you tell me what values should be compare? is cell type or what?

Comment: All values must be compared (cell_type,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)

Comment: For example, **2nd row** in file1.csv has values RBC, 378, 489, 278 and 374 while file2.csv has similar values in **15th row** RBC, 376, 487, 282 and 370. So, in the updated file 15th row must be brought to the place of 2nd row.

Comment: How should pairs of values be compared? What does "similar" mean — exactly?

Comment: It can be taken as a range. For a value x in file1.csv, (let's say) a value in range (x-50,x+50) found in file2.csv can be considered. That's what I mean by similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loops on this case. I tink just need to compare 1 columns of your data (example compare min_x columns) because I see Your data look similar for each columns (I mean for each columns has similar difference value compare to other table). So you can do loops like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',sep=';') # change the separator to the separator used
data2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',sep=';')
df_output = pd.DataFrame()
variable_want_to_compare = 'xmin'
for i in range(len(data1)):
    a = data1[variable_want_to_compare].iloc[i]
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        b = data2[variable_want_to_compare].iloc[j]
        if abs(a-b)<5: # tolerance of value differences
            df_output = df_output.append(data2.iloc[j],ignore_index=True)
```

I not compare each columns, because the data will complicated to sorting. If you want to sort each columns, just add more loops. But I tink you don't need it because difference of value from each columns look similar (base from your sample).

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of ease of coding and computation speed, the approach you can take is: first, turn the values in each column into a list (you can use pandas library). for example:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_1 = pd.read_csv('/PATH/FILE1.csv')
dataset_2 = pd.read_csv('/PATH/FILE2.csv')

x_min_1 = dataset_1['xmin'].values.tolist()
x_min_2 = dataset_2['xmin'].values.tolist()
```

so now you have the columns that you want to compared, converted into a list. now depending on what you want to do, there are a lot of ways to remove duplicates from the target list, for example list comprehension. if you want your `x_min_2` to have ONLY the values which are already in `x_min_1`, you can do a list comprehension:

```
x_min_2 = [i for i in x_min_2 if i in x_min_1]
```

you can obviously do this process for any column you want compared with any other column in any dataset. finally you will replace the target dataset column, with the new edited list:

```
dataset_2['xmin'] = pd.Series(x_min_2)
```